# Stopped Gem Update, Now Rails isn't recognized and unintall/reinstall didn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, version

I'm VERY new to this, so sorry if there's a simple fix, and please be step-by-step specific if you're kind enough to answer.

This is what I'm getting... Thanks!!!

```
$ rails -v
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:195:in `merge': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:195:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:364:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:364:in `configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:25:in `configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:5:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:380:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:380:in `<module:Bundler>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Pay more attention to your tags.  "fix" is for FIX protocol, not when you need to fix something.

Comment: any other suggestions?? I don't understand why completely taking out ruby and rails and reinstalling hasn't worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have a typo in your ~/.gemrc file, which should read:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you could try " rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p392 "  ... not sure if that would work or not, but worth a try. I'd make this as just a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough rep to do that yet, I don't think.

Comment: this didn't work, and I don't understand the first suggestion by Pigueiras...